# Keystate Inverter not working

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm coding an **ALT + ENTER** SDL Window minimiser/maximiser, however even though I've set an SDL Delay before the varibale `SMax` is changed, the window only minimises for a second before going back to It's original state. How do I make the minimisation/maximisation permanent until **ALT + ENTER** is pressed again?

```
if (keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_LALT] && keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_RETURN] && SMax)
                {
                    SDL_SetWindowFullscreen(window, 0);
                    SDL_SetWindowSize(window, 600, 400);
                    SDL_RenderPresent(renderTarget);
                    w = 600;
                    h = 400;
                    SDL_Delay(1000);
                    SMax = false;
                }

                if (keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_LALT] && keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_RETURN] && !SMax)
                {
                    SDL_SetWindowFullscreen(window, SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP);
                    SDL_RenderPresent(renderTarget);
                    SDL_Delay(1000);
                    SMax = true;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`keyState` doesn't get updated until the next call to `SDL_PumpEvents`, whether you put the program to sleep or not. You need to completely skip the second test until the next frame; an `else` will be enough.